# How to insert HTML in the body of an email message

Tags: c#

In my SharePoint site i am generating email if the ownership is reassigned to another user.This working properly.But some times the html tags are displaying in emails.

How to avoid this , its not happening frequently. Is there any other way to write emails ?

Here is my code :

```
public StringBuilder GTd(string strTitle, string strValue)
    {
        StringBuilder sbBody = new StringBuilder();
        sbBody.Length = 0;
        sbBody.Capacity = 0;
        try
        {
            sbBody.Append("<tr>");
            sbBody.Append("<td height=\"25\" style=\"padding-right:20px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#888;white-space:nowrap; font-style:normal;\">" + strTitle + "</td>");
            sbBody.Append("<td height=\"25\" style=\"padding-right:10px;font-family:Arial,Sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#888;\">•</td>");
            //  sbBody.Append("<td height=\"25\" style=\"padding-right:10px; font-size:13px; color:#222\"; margin:0=\"margin:0\" 0 0.3em 0;\">" + strValue + "</td>");
             sbBody.Append("<td height=\"25\" style=\"padding-right:10px; font-size:13px; color:#222; margin:0=\"margin:0\" 0 0.3em 0;\">" + strValue + "</td>");
            sbBody.Append("</tr>");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return sbBody;
    }
```

Comment: set email object IsBodyHtml property to true

Comment: I think we mainly need to see how you used GenerateTD now. as in short it just seems to have missed the <'s

Comment: Check if you have used escape \ correctly everywhere, then check if you mixed up ' and " somewhere. If you missed one something that should have been an HTML tag ended up being parsed as text.

Comment: IsBodyHtml is not present in stringbuilder object

Comment: no IsBodyHtml is part of the email message

Answer (score 0):

Having separate files for your css and htm will make things easier for you and the code will be much more maintainable.

then you can read both files and insert values in the html file for sending.
use curly braces with placement index in your html file where you will like to insert a value like title of some other content. eg <td>{0}</td> would be place to insert a title in the html file

```
    var cssPath = "path to css";
    var html ="";
    var htmlFile = "path to html file"
    using(StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(htmlFile))
       {  html = rd.ReadEnd();
         html = string.Format(html,value1,value2);//remember the values will be placed inside 
     the curly braces in the html file. and the number 
     of curly braces and arguments should match in exact order. 

        }
       //Now that you have your html file with the 
     contents you want  inside, you need to insert 
     the css file into the html. 


        using(StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(cssPath))
           {
            var css = rd.ReadToEnd();
             var index= html.IndexOf("<head>") +6;
         html = html.Insert(index, css)
          }
             // then remember to set IsBodyHtml = true in your mail message object
```